# Eclipse search everywhere

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

There is a `search everywhere` shortcut in Intellij IDEA(double clicking shift button), I'm wondering if similiar searching can be done in Eclipse. I did some googling, but it seems I can't search files/code at the same time in Eclipse.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean everywhere? CTRL + H does that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [search everywhere](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/searching-everywhere.html) (source code, databases, actions, elements of the user interface) from IntelliJ is (for Eclipse) split at least between:

- searches (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>): you can [define a search in files by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91984/how-do-i-hotkey-directly-to-file-search-tab-in-eclipse).
- searches in shortcuts (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>): for dearching the [list of key bindings](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-keybindings.htm)

Comment: Is there any way to have Intellij IDEA Ajax like search for files?

Comment: @Shota That I don't know. You could ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Control + 3 - search in all the settings. And my favourite Control + Shift + L (Only in Spring Source Tool Suite) - it's like Google for your source code. Is somehow similar to Symbol/ctag search in Intellij but it finds ALL occurences.

Both are very old features.

Answer (score 3):

For me, its a combination of:

`Cmd+Shift+R` : using wildcards like *, for the files
`Cmd+Shift+M` : for methods (also `Cmd+O` for a quick outline)
`Cmd+Shift+T` : for classes

I prefer keyboard shortcuts rather than the mouse, so these 3 shortcuts helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called [Quick Search](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/platform.php#quick-text-search) and can be activated using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>