# Can we give Open Resource in Eclipse with Double Shift shortcut(as in Intellij)

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am used to the IntelliJ IDE. I have used a plugin to map keys of IntelliJ to Eclipse. But for the Open Resource, still having the shortcut as `Ctrl + Shift + R`.
Is there any option to add Double Shift?

I have tried the Preference - General - Keys, but not able to update the shortcut to double shift.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831703/eclipse-search-everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think it's implicitly possible, and I'm not sure it's possible via a plugin either. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> is a [modifier key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key), which means it usually does something in combination with other keys. Even in IJ, if you look at the keymap, there is no shortcut assigned to `Search everywhere`, so it's probably implemented as a custom feature (maybe not so relevant, but it's also not disabled if you assign a shortcut).

[image: IJ keymap]

There are plugins which reproduce the IJ keymap in Eclipse, such as [IntelliJIdeaKeymap4Eclipse](https://github.com/IntelliJIdeaKeymap4Eclipse/IntelliJIdeaKeymap4Eclipse) (There could possibly others which I don't know yet) but not all features are supported (see below).

[image: IntelliJIdeaKeymap4Eclipse]

I haven't developed any Eclipse plugins so I don't know the limitations of the framework, so I guess it may be worth trying to contact the author of the above plugin and ask about the feature, or search alternative plugins.

Comment: Thanks @mofic. I have already tried on of the plungs. I will check this one also.

Comment: @JitheshGopinathan Sorry if I've not been clear enough. The plugin also DOES NOT support double shift. That's why I mentioned it may be worth contacting the maintainer, perhaps he knows if there's a possibility to add it or not.

Comment: Ohhhh.. Thanks @mofic. I will have a try.